# C/C++ — use the __funcsig__ macro to get a function signature?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hook

I'm trying to find the signature of a function exported from a DLL and define exactly the same callback function for hooking.

It is the need of current project I am working on.

The following is what I have done to find the function location.

```
HMODULE hModd = LoadLibraryEx("xxx.dll",NULL,DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);

dosHeader = ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModd);
    /*if(((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModd)->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"wow","exe",MB_OK);/**/
    ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)hModd + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModd)->e_lfanew);
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exports = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((BYTE *)hModd + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);
    PVOID names = (BYTE *)hModd + exports->AddressOfNames;
    WORD *pOrds = (WORD*)((BYTE*)hModd + exports->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
    DWORD* addr = (DWORD*)((BYTE*)hModd + exports->AddressOfFunctions); 
    for (int i = 0; i < exports->NumberOfNames; ++i,addr++)
        {
            char funcName[255];
            char const *target = "Test";
            ZeroMemory(funcName,sizeof(funcName));
            //strcpy(funcName,(char*)((BYTE *)hModd + ((DWORD *)names)[i]));
            if(strcmp((char*)((BYTE *)hModd + ((DWORD *)names)[i]),target))
            {
                printf("Export: %s Address: %X \n", (char*)((BYTE *)hModd + ((DWORD *)names)[i]),*addr);
                offsetTarget = *addr;
            }
        }
```

How can I use the `__funcsig__` macro to get the DLL function signature?

`__funcsig__` generally returns signature of function enclosing it.

Comment: Note that the exports are ordered lexicographically, which means that you can use a binary search to find an export with a particular name.  No need for a linear search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `__FUNCSIG__` for this:  as you said, it yields the signature of the enclosing function.

There's no way to get the signature of an arbitrary function exported by an arbitrary module.  The information simply doesn't exist:  you'd need some form of additional metadata describing the type of the function.

Comment: It depends.  What "work" needs to be done?  If you can identify the calling convention of the target function, then you can figure out where the arguments are and which registers are "important" to the call.

Comment: If you don't have a header file or source code for the DLL you need to use a disasassembler (the free version of IDA Pro should be fine) to investigate the function and find out the parameters and return value.

Comment: @divideandconquer.se : no dis-assembler allowed... only code.

Comment: It is not possible to reliably autodetect the input and output of any method in any DLL.